How would I ensure I measured these windows correctly for replacement with egress?
I've got two bedrooms in my basement with no egress windows. I measured the concrete opening of both and found the one flush with the parging to be 20"x37", but the one that was recessed in with the wooden frame had a concrete opening of 20.5"x37". I got a quote for these sizes from a local company that does custom fit egress windows, and they are just big enough to meet the minimum egress requirements. I've held off on ordering them because I'm paranoid that I measured them wrong and if I order the wrong size, I'll be out a bunch of money. The quote just gave me two windows that fit a 20"x37" opening, so if one is off by 1/2", is that easy to fix?
[


You would be best served by asking  the manufacturer these questions . Generally a rough opening that is 1/2 inch too big is not a great issue.  That is why shims are made.

I hope I'm understanding correctly, but if you're saying that one of your window rough openings is 1/2" too big for the window, then you'll be fine. Shimming and spray foaming will lock the window in perfectly. You might need a tiny bit of wood trim on the outside to cover a gap.
